# FlashBag without page refresh or redirect

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an Event Subscriber with function `setAcademicCalendar`. I want to catch exceptions, display an error message in the flash bag and terminate form submit. Basically, I want to stay in the form (no redirects), give the user an error message and don't save the form.

I have two problems. 1. I don't know to terminate the process 2. The flash message is only displayed after a page refresh.

```
private function setAcademicCalendar(FormEvent $event) {

    /** @var CalendarEvent $calendar_event */
    $calendar_event = $event->getData();

    if ($calendar_event->getCalendar() instanceof Calendar) {
        try {
            $sem = $this
                ->container
                ->get('academic_calendar')
                ->getSemester($calendar_event->getStart());
            $calendar_event->setSemester($sem);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->container->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        FormEvents::SUBMIT  => 'submitData',
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA  => 'preSetData',
    ];
}

/**
 * @param FormEvent $event
 */
public function submitData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $this->setAcademicCalendar($event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this  without  redirection / refresh  forget about validation in strict php. Only   some strict frontend techs  - like  angular js ,  vue.js  with some   api calls